# Condition for subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition

As I learned, a subset $H$ of a group $G$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if :

$(1)$ $H$ is closed under the binary operation of $G$.

$(2)$ The identity element $e$ of $G$ is in $H$.

$(3)$ For all $a$ in $H$, $a^{-1}$ belongs in $H$ also.

But isn't second condition redundant? I think it can be derived from $(1)$ and $(3)$, for let $a\in H$, then $a^{-1}\in H$ by $(3)$, and by $(1)$, $aa^{-1}=e$ is an element of $H$, proving $(2)$.

Answer (score 4):

You need the second one for the subset to be non-empty. If you take $H =\emptyset$, then 1) and 3) are fullfilled but $H$ is not a group.

Edit: I prefer to combine 1) and 3) for example and actually rephrase the second condition in terms of the existence of some element:

A subset $H \subset G$ is a subgroup iff $H$ is non-empty and for all $a, b \in H$ we have $ab^{-1} \in H$.

Comment: But doesn't "closed" subset in (1) already include the meaning that this subset is non-empty?

Comment: No, $(1)$ the only thing that tells us is that "if $a \in H$ and $b \in H$ then $ab \in H$", but the implication remains true if the part "$a \in H$ and $b \in H$" is false (is in the case when $H=\varnothing $).

Comment: No. You get that for all $a,b \in H$ we have $ab \in H$. This is vacuously true for the empty set.