# Properties of a ring $R$ guaranteed by an equivalence relation and certain operations

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and let $S$ be a nonempty subset of $R$.

1) Consider the relation ~ on $R$ given by $a$~$b\Leftrightarrow a-b\in S$. Which properties must $S$ have so that ~ is an equivalence relation?

2) Suppose you have $S$ such that ~ is an equivalence relation. Consider the set $R/ S:= \{[a] :a\in R\}$ of equivalence classes of $R$ under ~. What additional properties must $S$ have so that the operations $[a]+[b]=[a+b]$ and $[a][b]=[ab]$ are well-defined for all $a,b\in R$?

Now, **before** you answer this question, please give a yes or no response to my answers below.

1) $S$ must have an additive identity (reflexive property of ~), an additive inverse (reflexive property of ~), commutativity of addition (since if $a+b=a-(-b)\in S$, then $b+a=-((-b)-a)=-(-(a+b))=a+b\in S$)), and associativity of addition (since if $(a+b)+c=(a-(-b))-(-c)\in S$, then $a+(b+c)=a-(-(b-(-c)))=(a+b)+c\in S$). I'm really unsure about my reasoning for the last two properties (it's **most likely** not enough or **entirely incorrect**).

2) I'm stuck here.

Edit: sorry about the last paragraph. Shouldn’t ‘ve been so negative

Comment: You asked 17 questions and have answers to 13 of these. You didn't accept any of them. I think you should consider to read this article about the appropriate behaviour: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @amrsa I’m so sorry. I didn’t even know I had to accept answers lol. I’ll do that right now. And I have wayyy more questions than answers due to my lack of understanding.

Comment: @fordjames And you don't. But you should accept one answer for each question, provided there's one that you find really useful, or the one that suits you better.

Comment: Remove or rephrase the last paragraph of this question or it will get downvoted out of existence.

Comment: Yeah gotchu @JakeMirra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The answer to be angled at is

> $(S,+)$ must be a subgroup of $(R,+)$

Each of the following points corresponds to an axiom of equivalence relations:

1. $0\in S$
2. For all $a\in S$, $-a\in S$.
3. For all $a, b\in S$, $a-b\in S$.

You may recognize these conditions as [the subgroup test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3289339/29335).

You explained correctly that the first is due to the reflexive property, but I wouldn't say that inverses are due to reflexivity. Try to sort out which ones the last two correspond to.

You don't have to worry about commutativity or associativity since *these are inherited from the group $(R,+)$*.  The operation used in $S$ is the same $+$, so it's obvious a subset of $R$ can't violate the commutativity or associativity of $+$ in $R$.

---

2) The answer to be angled at here is

> $S$ must be an ideal (two-sided) of $R$.

There are already [good explanations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/446492/29335) as to how the axioms of an ideal justify that the "obvious" multiplication operation $[a][b]=[ab]$ is well-defined.  If $S$ is not an ideal, then this proposed operation doesn't work because it is not a well-defined map.  (The addition operation $[a]+[b]=[a+b]$ is already well defined since $S$ is a normal subgroup of $R$.) Finally, the multiplication distributes over addition so that $R/S$ really is a ring.

What you wrote for this second point has virtually nothing to comment on. It looks like a confused mess of guesses.

Comment: @rschweib, I have a completely unrelated question, but just to confirm, is $1$ *never* equal to $0$ in a ring as $1$ is *always* the multiplicative identity? Also, is there a way other than through comments that users can chat directly?

Comment: @fordjones $0=1$ iff the ring is the zero ring $\{0\}$

Comment: @fordjones You can start a chat room for us.

Comment: @rschweib I don't know how to do that without making it public and calling it some random name. Anyways, does the **additive identity** always have to be $0$ in a ring and does the **additive inverse** of an element $a$ always have to be $-a$?

Comment: @fordjones https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22037/how-do-i-invite-a-user-to-chat. I found this by searching “invite chat” in meta

Comment: @fordjones Look, normally $0$ is *notation* for the additive identity, and $-a$ is *notation* for the additive inverse of $a$.  But you *can* put an abelian group structure on $\mathbb Z$ so that the integer $0$ is no longer the identity, and the inverse of $1$ is no longer $-1$.  The difference is between notating an element of $\mathbb Z$ and notating an element of a group whose elements did not previously have such handy labels.